# Arduino and Bitwise, unexpected result

Tags: arduino

Getting my self a bit confused here.

I would like to test if a set of bits (3 bits) contains a bit in a certain postion.

```
if (B110 & B010 == B010)
```

(B110 being the number to check, B010 the bit I want to see if is there)

The above code isn't giving me the expected out come, both B110 is true and B101 is true. I am pretty sure that I need to use a &(and) to test with the mask B010.

My understanding is that B110 & B010 would be equal to B010 and that B101 & B010 would equal B000. But my if statement is run with both test bits?

I am coding in an Arduino, I'm sure that it's a simple misunderstanding on my behalf but not sure where.

Comment: I couldn't help but laugh at the pun.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `if ((B110 & B010) == B010)`

At the moment it's running as `if (B110 & (B010 == B010))` which will always be true.

As [this table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) shows, *==* and *!=* have a higher precedence than *&*, *|* etc.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was about to say, I can only add that it's completely insane of C's designers that theu didn't make & stronger than ==, forcing us to litter our code with enough parentheses to make it look like lisp.

Comment: @dren Absolutely ;)  As a general rule of thumb, if I'm doing a calculation in an IF I *always* put the calculation in parentheses of their own.

Comment: If there's ever any doubt, I use extra parens.  I don't know the precedence of operators, but I *do* know that the compiler will obey parens.

Comment: Thanks adding the parentheses works fine. I didn't know the precedence of operators that far down.

Comment: If you don't know operator precedence, don't blame Brian and Dennis.  The precedence of the bit-wise operators can be annoying, but remember that the nuisance can go both ways -- having it be too high can cause bit-wise operations where you don't want them.

Answer (score 3):

The "`== B010`" is actually unnecessary in this test. In C, `0` represents "false," while any nonzero value is considered "true." `B110 & B010` (or any other value with that bit set) will return `B010`, which is not equal to `0`, so the test succeeds.